# jQuery effects with exposed filters

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, views

I am trying to produce a view with exposed filters, where:

1. The options are listed as text links, like a menu
2. The page automatically updates when a link is clicked
3. jQuery effects appear to seamlessly 'reorder' and remove items smoothly

eg: http://thisiseyeweb.co.uk/our-work#filter=.e-commerce

I have solved 1 & 2 by using Better Exposed Filters and settings in Views. So I can produce the list of links that make up the menu, and the ajax action to change what is displayed. But I can't make items that should no longer display 'fade out' or remove themselves in a prettier fashion, like the link above.

Many thanks.

Comment: You may look into this http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html and also check out the grid module for this: http://drupal.org/project/masonry. Maybe it helps you getting your way...

Comment: This looks pretty, but I think it's more focused on responsive layouts rather than removing filtered items?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this https://drupal.org/project/views_quicksand

It integrates this plugin http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ with views.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Job for Isotopes http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Here is a module for Drupal implimentation https://drupal.org/project/isotope

This one  is for Views

https://drupal.org/project/views_isotope

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I guess you can't do it with the normal behaviour of view exposed filter... My guess would be to do it all by yourself in JS.

1. Display all your items, like no filtered
2. Somehow add a class to the row, identifying the data to be filtered on
3. List your filter items, on a view attachment or in a block
4. Somehow add a class to these items, identifying the data that they'll display
5. Add JS to fetch identifier in item's class, and fade on click all rows which don't have the identifier

Though, I hope somebody has a more views-friendly answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it's a fair suggestion =] I'm still hoping for a more views-friendly answer, as you say.